# How to pull events logs from Amazon Web Service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How to pull all the events logs using AWS java rest api ? I want all the events logs for further monitoring.can anyone help me for finding some document or reference code or any kind of help which is helpful for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "event logs"? Are you referring to CloudWatch metrics, web logs, S3 logs, CloudFront log, etc? What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I am considering all that logs which is generated when some event is perform on AWS. e.g. someone login in aws, it generate logs,someone working with S3, it generate logs etc...I want to collect all that logs for monitoring using java api.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no single "AWS log".** Many AWS services have their own capability to provide logs, so you would need to access/retrieve those logs separately. Therefore, it depends on which services you use.

Services that exist specifically to provide logs includes:

- [AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html): You can use AWS CloudTrail to get a history of AWS API calls and related events for your account.
- [Amazon CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/WhatIsCloudWatch.html): Amazon CloudWatch monitors your Amazon Web Services (AWS) resources and the applications you run on AWS in real-time. You can use CloudWatch to collect and track metrics, which are the variables you want to measure for your resources and applications.
- [Amazon CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html): You can use Amazon CloudWatch Logs to monitor, store, and access your log files from Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances, AWS CloudTrail, and other sources. You can then retrieve the associated log data from CloudWatch Logs.
- [AWS Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html): AWS Config provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

Many of the individual services on AWS have their own method of generating logs, such as:

- [Amazon S3 bucket logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html)
- [Elastic Load Balancing access logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html)
- [Amazon RDS Database Log Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html)
- [VPC Flow Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html)

These logs are, of course, totally separate to any logs generate by applications you are running on Amazon EC2 instances, such as Apache web logs.

**Bottom Line:** You will need an understanding of the services you have configured in AWS in order to figure out what logging data is therefore available.